# Simplifying modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If I have the equation: $(43 \times 172)(\mod 5)$, may I simplify before the multiplication?
i.e   $43(\mod 5) \times 172(\mod 5)$

Comment: @Moo Can numbers with an exponent be reduced as well? i.e. 1001^7 (mod 6) reduced to (1001(mod 6) )^7 (mod 6)

Comment: With exponents, note that you can only simplify the *base* of the exponent.  For example $12^{6}\pmod{5}\not\equiv 2^1\pmod{5}$ but instead is $12^6\pmod{5}\equiv 2^6\pmod{5}\equiv 4\pmod{5}$

Answer (score 0):

In general, given the hypotheses that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$, you can prove that these conditions imply the following properties:

$$a+x\equiv b+y\pmod{n}$$

and

$$a\cdot x \equiv b\cdot y\pmod{n}$$

This second mentioned property also implies that you can replace bases of exponents (*but not the exponents themselves directly, other tools exist for that though*):

$$a^z\equiv b^z\pmod{n}$$

For your specific example, yes these work in the way you hope that you *can* just "replace" things by smaller/simpler to work with numbers so long as they are equivalent.  E.g. $43\cdot 172\equiv 3\cdot 2\pmod{5}$

In terms of *notation* however, in pure mathematics "mod" should really only appear at the tail end of the entire line.  It is not so much an operation so much as it is a setting in which you are working.  This is contrary to mod in a computer science sense where someone might interpret your statement as $(43\%5)\cdot (172\%5)=3\cdot 2=6$ and say that $6\neq 1$ while in pure maths we are technically working with equivalence classes of the mod5 relation and here $6\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.